# SQL Server Transpose

Tags: sql-server, transpose, database-normalization

I want to transpose a `Select` but can't get my head around `Pivot` and I am even more perplexed by the following found at numerous tutorials:

"Had the source data been properly normalized there would been no need to transform the columns and rows. If you find yourself needing to perform this type of transformation regularly, then you have a problem with your schema design".

Specifically how would normalization enable a `Select` to return the transposed values for:

```
SELECT 
    Date, Activity 
FROM 
    EVENTS 
WHERE 
    CITY = 'Seattle'
```

(i.e. rather than event dates going down column1 I'd like the dates to go across as columns)

Comment: How many dates are there, and could the number vary?  The answer to this will determine whether or not you need dynamic SQL to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the quoted statement refers more to unpivoting than pivoting. e.g. instead of having a column for city, you have columns "Seattle", "SomeOtherCity", "SomeOtherOtherCity" or something like that. Normalising your data makes it easier to use PIVOT because you don't have to normalise it (UNPIVOT) then PIVOT, I guess. It wouldn't outright enable a PIVOT without a PIVOT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can choose a method similar to following sample,
I used [dynamic SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/build-sql-server-dynamic-sql-query-example.aspx) with CTE statement and CASE operator.
I just used the CTE expression for converting datetime to date data type not to repeat convertion in each CASE statement

```
declare @mm varchar(2) = datepart(mm,getdate())
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'
;with cte as (
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(dd,[date]) dd,
        convert(date,[date]) [date],
        Activity
    FROM 
        [events]
)
SELECT
    case when dd = 1 then Activity end as ''' + '01/'+@mm+'/2016' + ''',
    case when dd = 2 then Activity end as ''' + '01/'+@mm+'/2016' + ''',
    case when dd = 3 then Activity end as ''' + '01/'+@mm+'/2016' + ''',
    case when dd = 17 then Activity end as ''' + '01/'+@mm+'/2016' + ''',
    case when dd = 18 then Activity end as ''' + '01/'+@mm+'/2016' + ''',
    case when dd = 19 then Activity end as ''' + '01/'+@mm+'/2016' + ''',
    case when dd = 20 then Activity end as ''' + '01/'+@mm+'/2016' + ''',
    case when dd = 28 then Activity end as ''' + '01/'+@mm+'/2016' + ''',
    case when dd = 29 then Activity end as ''' + '01/'+@mm+'/2016' + ''',
    case when dd = 30 then Activity end as ''' + '01/'+@mm+'/2016' + '''
FROM cte'
print @sql
exec sp_executeSQL @sql
```

Of course a [dynamic pivot query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-dynamic-pivot-table-example-code.aspx) will fit your requirement better.
You can start by static pivot examples to understand the structure, then work on your sample case. At the final step, you can convert your code to dynamic pivot query